# Почему появляется рамка вокруг картинок в google chrome?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Из-за чего может появляться эта рамка? В Опере и Edge её нет, но присутствует у некоторых пользователей Google Chrome, но тоже не у всех. Верстал любитель, может не те стили использовал?

[image: outline img block]

сам сайт https://wedex.com.ua/ru/

Comment: Чтобы сайт отображался одинаково во всех браузер рекомендую использовать normalize.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при devtools'е если синим подсвечен flex то он будет оборачивать внутринее элементы, что бы показать, мл это мои дети. Просто нажмите на flex и все пропадет.

Если не в этом проблема, то проставте border: none или outline: none

 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: помог решить вопрос css "outline: none"